# Picture field in user table

Tags: 7

I can see the picture field in the user table, and it seems the field accepts a picture address.
I want to allow users to upload their picture to the site.

Is there any module or code to use this field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the user account settings in page `admin/user/settings`, the option for changing user picture is "Picture support."

Comment: thank u.can we use imagecache for uploaded user picture?

Answer (score 5):

User pictures, the pictures associated with a user account, are handled from the User module.
You need to enable their support with the "Picture support" option you find in admin/user/settings.

The support works if the directory for the files has been correctly set, and Drupal has the permission to write files in that directory; the path reported in "Picture image path" must exists.

Comment: thank u.can we use imagecache for uploaded user picture?

Comment: @a.v You can use Imagecache with any images uploaded to Drupal, including the ones uploaded with the Upload module.

Comment: i can use imagecache with cck  field but how to set imagecache for upload user picture field (upload module?). more help plz.

Comment: Imagecache creates only copies with different dimensions of an image that has been uploaded to a Drupal site; it doesn't upload the image itself, and you can use any module for uploading the image.